# how to create an variable with an text selection in flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield, text-editor

I would like to create a variable with selected text from a textfield.

Example = When I select some text, I could click on a button to save this text. I have no idea how to do this, and I hope someone could give me some hints.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try [selection_controls_example](https://github.com/jamesblasco/selection_controls_example). You can create custom action buttons. Or just use [SelectableText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SelectableText-class.html) and create your own button.

Comment: hi, it do not work for me.